# AD for sign in only as well as group/role mapping

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory

I have 2 different use cases for AD within the same app:

- Sign a user in and nothing else
- Sign in and read group/role claims, remove deactivated users etc.

Both are unique by user account, but live in the same app. It's important to avoid admin consent for the first case.

How can this be achieved? 2 different AD app registrations like "MyApp Simple" and "MyApp Enterprise"? Or is there something better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try two different app registrations or just set the logic within the app itself and apply it based on the roles. From what I understand you will have certain users that have the same permissions but have different user experiences depending on where they sign in from? If this is the case you can just enable or disable the group/role claims in the app itself depending on the permissions applied to the user. I was able to achieve something very similar following [this guide and repository](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims). Please see if it helps.